# Devices on subnet cannot access each other but can access internet

Tags: networking, router, subnet

I live in university halls and only have access to the internet and the network through one ethernet port. I have a TP-Link R860 router (wired only) and a TP-Link simple switch.

If I connect using the simple switch, one device can access the internet and all the other devices on the switch. If I use the router, everything can access the internet, but cannot access each other on the subnet.

How can I connect all my devices so that they can all access each other as well as the internet?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried plugging the switch into the router ? Also have you checked the manual to see if you can disable any of the built in network security features ?

Comment: The fact that your devices cannot see each other when all connected to the router can only be the consequence of some wrong setting on the router itself: routers are supposed to make this sort of communication possible. In any case, check that you have DHCP enabled, that your router gets an IP from your University network (i.e., it does not act as a gateway, or a switch, but as a proper router); iable VLAN if you have it on.

Comment: @Lawrence - I can't believe I never thought of that, but it seems to work, at least better than anything else so far.

Comment: @MariusMatutiae - DHCP is enabled, the uni network is connected to the router via WAN and uses a static IP. All router security and firewalls are turned off and set to allow anyway.

Comment: What happens if you connect the switch to the router, then the devices to the switch (with all devices configured to use DHCP) ?

Comment: @NickW - It seems to be working, so far at least

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you are using static IP addressing when connecting via switch and not updating it to DHCP when you put router between the Uni network and your local network segment.

Answer (score 0):

Plug the Switch into the Router as a workaround for now.

If you can find out if there are any features on the router that prevent LAN ports from talking to each other, you will probably need to disable that so that you only need to use the Router